# Summing vector elements in a for loop, and reset the summing after certain number of vector elements

Tags: c++, vector

Let's define two vectors, their size is 30. I want to push_back to the summed value of the `vector2`, in the range of the `vec1` elements:  `1-6, 7-12,13-18,19-24.` Which means, I reset the summed value from vec2, once the `vec1` elements 6, 12, 18 and so on complete (including their repetition).

For example, the first sum from vector2 will be completed at `vec2[19]`, because of the elements of the `vec1` 6 ends at that position. Then we can reset the sum =0, and start over in the same fashion. Each step I would like to push_back the sum to a new vector and carry on the process.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

// return type vector
int main(){
vector<double> summed;
int limit = 6;
double sum = 0;

    vector <int> vec1 {1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6,10,10,10,10,12,13,14,14,15,16,20};
    vector <double> vec2 {100,1,1200,1130,1140,20,3,32,33,34.0,3,23,3,33,4,43,4,6,36,64,1201,10,120,10,12,13,14,124,125,16,20};


for (int i = 0; i < vec2.size(); ++i)
    if (vec1[i] <= limit)
        sum += vec2[i];
    else
    {
        summed.push_back(sum);
        limit += 6;
        sum = vec2[i];
    }
for (int i =0; i<=summed.size(); i++)
{
 cout << " the elements of the summed vector "<<summed[i] <<endl;
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
     the elements of the summed vector 3912                                                                                                
 the elements of the summed vector 1353                                                                                                
 the elements of the summed vector 292                                                                                                 
 the elements of the summed vector 0
```

Four groups from the `vec1` elements

```
1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,6,
10,10,10,10,12,
13,14,14,15,16,
20
```

Comment: WHat does this phrase " For example, the first sum from vector2 will be completed at vec2[19]" mean?

Comment: It means that the first segment of the range `1-6`,  elements from the vec1 will be completed at that position.  So we take the sum of all the elements from vec2, pushback to a new vector and then set that zero again to start over.

Comment: @Izero_field, "I want to push_back to the summed value of the vector2," Till now I have though that you can push back to a vector not to some "summed value".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, it's about summing iteratively of the vector elements  vec2[i]. But the iteration will depend on the range of the vector elements `vec[i]`.  Please let me know if it's still unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
vector<double> summed;
int limit = 6;
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < vec2.size(); ++i)
{
    if (vec1[i] <= limit)
        sum += vec2[i];
    else
    {
        summed.push_back(sum);
        limit += 6;
        sum = vec2[i];
    }
}
summed.push_back(sum);
```

Note that this is assuming `vec1` is sorted in non-decreasing order.

Comment: @zero_field no. Take your example, the if condition will fail for the first time at `i = 20` when `vec1[i] = 10`. At this point, we push the current sum and if we set `sum = 0` then we'll miss `vec2[20]` since `i` will be `21` in the next iteration.

Comment: Shouldn't sum = 0?; I have updated the question using your suggestions. There are 5 group segments in the `vec1`, but it seems the vector size is 4, as can be seen from the `cout`.

Comment: Understood, but where is the 5th sum? 
 But, the last element from `vec1 `represents the sum 20 from the `vec2`. It shouldn't be 0, right?

Comment: Actually, it did not. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, i see, `sum` must be push backed once more after the for loop is over. Sorry about the inconvenience. I updated my answer to fix that issue.

Comment: Do we have to close the parenthesis `{} `of the for loop to include the `vec[i]` after else condition?